# Colab pro does not provide more than 16 gb of ram

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

Today i upgraded my account to Colab pro. Although it prints the ram as:

```
Your runtime has 27.3 gigabytes of available RAM
    
    You are using a high-RAM runtime!
```

when I start training my model, it gives the error below.

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 88.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.90 GiB total capacity; 14.75 GiB already allocated; 75.75 MiB free; 14.95 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Hyperparameters of my model:

```
args_dict = dict(
    #data_dir="", # path for data files
    output_dir="", # path to save the checkpoints
    model_name_or_path='t5-large',
    tokenizer_name_or_path='t5-large',
    max_seq_length=600,
    learning_rate=3e-4,
    weight_decay=0.0,
    adam_epsilon=1e-8,
    warmup_steps=0,
    train_batch_size=4,
    eval_batch_size=4,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=16,
    n_gpu=1,
    early_stop_callback=False,
    fp_16=True, # if you want to enable 16-bit training then install apex and set this to true
    opt_level='O1', # you can find out more on optimisation levels here https://nvidia.github.io/apex/amp.html#opt-levels-and-properties
    max_grad_norm=1.0, # if you enable 16-bit training then set this to a sensible value, 0.5 is a good default
    seed=42,
)
```

Colab pro not providing all ram. My code only works if train_batch_size = 1. What causes this? Any ideas?

Note: I get the same error when I run the code in Kaggle (16Gb). So, what I get with colab pro?

Comment: Hello : how heavy are the data you are using ? can you post here a minimal example of your code ? In particular the training loop please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your error, the 16 GB are referring to the graphics card, not the ram.

As far as I know, using colab-pro enables you to use a graphics card with up to 16GB of VRAM.

You can check the VRAM amount by running the following code.

```
gpu_info = !nvidia-smi
gpu_info = '\n'.join(gpu_info)
if gpu_info.find('failed') >= 0:
  print('Select the Runtime > "Change runtime type" menu to enable a GPU accelerator, ')
  print('and then re-execute this cell.')
else:
  print(gpu_info)
```

Maybe you use a smaller batch size than 4?